# QuoteLineItems Stop Adding Opportunity Products

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem

We need to be able to add opportunity products without adding them to the quotelineitems.

This is because our special pricing desk needs to inspect each product before it is added to an appended quote. If it is auto added through opportunities, it could inadvertently be sent to incorrectly to our partners.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @SantanuBoral My latest is an insert trigger that checks status and user and deletes the record. This works but causes other issues.  I have also tried is syncing and turning off syncing. but none of these have worked